# How simulate a Windows like admin password prompt in Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, non-root-user, privileges

I use `mint install` application a lot but don't think it is safe if 
I allow the normal user I use to have full privileges over it. I was
wondering if there is a way to gain access to this application only when
root password is entered. Basically 
 be able to use something like the admin password prompt of windows when installing a new application in terminal. I know I can log into root with 
su but I know that's definitely not safe. Any Ideas?

Edit: Again, I don't want to give privileges to the normal user using sudo or chmod or anything else.

Comment: As I said earlier, I don't want to give privileges to the normal user.

Comment: Can you create a new user specifically (password protected) for that program and change the ownership of that program to that specific user? So with you only having the password, no one else can access it.

Comment: @JechtTyre you can use `su -c 'command_to_run'` if that's what you want.

Comment: Logging into root with `su` is perfectly fine, you just shouldn't live your whole life in there. If you want to make a command only executable by root, go for it

Comment: I think the closest the Unix desktop systems have to Windows UAC is `pkexec name-of-program`. By default, it'll prompt for the root password every time it's run.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to do something that requires root privileges, you need to use some method of gaining root privileges, which on most modern systems means `su`, `sudo`, or a wrapper around one of these. What's dangerous about running commands as root (whether it's with `su` or `sudo`) is that it gives you a lot more ways to damage your system. So you should only run a command as root when the command actually requires it.

The main difference between `su` and `sudo` in their typical configuration is that for `sudo`, you type the same password as when you log in, whereas `su` requires a different password (the password of the `root` user). For a typical single-user machine, there isn't a significant difference between the two in terms of security. It's also possible to configure `sudo` not to require a password.

If you're working in a terminal and you want to run a command as root, with `su`, run:

```
su -c 'somecommand an_argument another_argument'
```

With `sudo`:

```
sudo somecommand an_argument another_argument
```

Either way, you'll be prompted for a password (the root password for `su`, your own password for `sudo`). Sudo can remember your password and not ask you again for the next few minutes; with `su`, you'll have to type it again each time.

You can also get a graphical prompt to type your password (with `gksu`, `kdesu`, …), but if you're already working in a terminal, that's less convenient.

Comment: This does not work with applications that need a shell. gives TTY error. e.g. su -c 'vim hello.txt'

Comment: @JechtTyre You mentioned working in a terminal in your question, in which case `su -c 'vim hello.txt'` would work (but `sudoedit` can be more convenient and more secure). If you're not already in a terminal, then you can use `gksu` or `kdesu` or the like to get a GUI prompt.

Answer (score -1):

While keeping in mind that there are no free meals, it's possible to minimize risk.

If you'd like to run your script as root and immediately exit without password prompt and `exit` command then you'll have to compromise a bit.

The following solution lets you store your encrypted twice (or more) `root` password anywhere with the current user permissions.

High level:

1. Encrypting `root` password in `base64` twice once and placing the file anywhere (can be 1234.txt, for example).
2. Invoking `expect` script with argument (the string from above decoded)
3. `Expect` runs the desired script and exits.
4. Cleanup file under `/root` invoked from `expect` and deletes `bash_history` (of common user) lines containing `root`, password encrypted file, and `base64`. To remove any trace the script was invoked (from common user perspective). This script is only accessible by `root` user.

So over all, it seems that from the common users' perspective, this script was never run, and it doesn't contain any sensitive password.

Furthermore, double `base64` encryption, seems pretty random to innocent to me (though I'm not security expert, I would not recognize it as 2x`base64`). For example:

```
V1c5MVFYSmxWMlZzWTI5dFpRbz0K decrypted to YouAreWelcome
```

Coding the password twice in `base64` **once**:

```
$ cat pass.txt | base64 | base64 > innocent_name.txt
$ rm pass.txt
```

Then:

Running the script:

```
$ ./root_wrap.exp "$(cat innocent_name.txt | base64 -d | base64 -d)"
```

Expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set root_user root;
set root_pass [ lindex $argv 0 ];

spawn bash
expect "*$ "
send -- "whoami\r"
expect "*$ "
send -- "su $root_user\r"
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "$root_pass\r"
expect "*# "
send -- "./whoam.sh\r"
expect "*# "
send -- "/root/rm_trace.sh\r"
expect "*# "
send -- "exit\r"
send -- "whoami\r"
expect "*$ "
expect eof
```

Cleanup history script `/root/rm_trace.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i '/base64/d' /home/<user>/.bash_history
sed -i '/root_wrapp/d' /home/<user>/.bash_history
sed -i '/innocent_name/d' /home/<user>/.bash_history
```

Sample bash script to be run as root:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 echo "now running as root"
 whoami
```

Comment: Since I will run this script in the normal user environment, doesn't that mean the  root user password indicated in the script can be accessed by opening the script or reverse compiling it?

Comment: @JechtTyre I've edited the answer to add another layer of defense. Now, it'll `cat` the password from `randomname.txt` file. Hence the password will not be shown anywhere in history and won't be possible to back engineer it. Though, you might want to rename the files `root_wrapper.exp` so not to give hints ;-)

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that a file with the root password is accessible by a non-admin account without a prompt.

Comment: @JechtTyre `There are no free meals`. If you want convenience, you must pay some price.

Comment: @JechtTyre updated answer with encrypted password.