# Approve sudo commands attempted to be executed by a non-admin by password (like user account control on Windows)

Tags: sudo

I am trying to set up an admin system where non-admins can request admin privileges temporarily. I was thinking of letting multiple people use my Raspberry Pi, so I wanted to create a system where they have to enter a code to run sudo temporarily. It is kinda like in Windows 10/11 where the non-admin user needs to enter an admin's password to be granted temporary admin privileges. I didn't find anyone trying to attempt this when I research about it (correct me if I'm wrong). Is there any way to implement this?

Update: I'm not looking for 2FA. I'm looking for a unique code that can be randomized (but not automatically). As I said, I would like it like when there is a prompt for an Admin Password, but instead of an admin password, it is a code. Apologies if it may be a little complicated.

Note that I don't want it implemented on the GUI, only the terminal for non-admins.

Comment: This? https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/how-set-2-factor-authentication-login-and-sudo/ https://multifactor.my/docs/linux-sudo-2fa/ https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-use-two-factor-authentication-with-sudo-and-ssh-on-linux-with-google-authenticator/

Comment: This is close to what I was looking for, except I would like a unique admin code that doesn't randomize every single minute. I updated the question for more clarity

Comment: How will you check for this code on the server side? Have you thought your question through? People use Google authenticator for a reason.

Comment: I was thinking of a code that can be checked by only admins. I might try using 2FA, or may possibly try using Admin passwords instead. Is there a way to use admin passwords for prompt?

Comment: Unless you tightly restrict the jobs they can run, if you give the user root privileges once, even "temporarily",  then if they want to, they can effectively retain them forever.  They could do `sudo bash` to get a root shell that would persist until reboot, even after their sudo time window expires.   Or create a private setuid binary that grants them root whenever they run it, or patch various system daemons to include a backdoor, etc, etc.

Comment: I was planning to block it if the people using my linux knows that. They don't. I'm planning to let them play around after showing commands they can do. Anyways, I might close the question because I don't need to do this, but if anyone can help me on this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I just found a question that has exactly what I wanted.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149928/how-simulate-a-windows-like-admin-password-prompt-in-linux